# How to loop commands continuously from prompt

Tags: bash, loops, ubuntu

Is there a way to loop the commands until the number of names from the prompt, i dont want it to just limit the number of users but to continuisly add names to the prompt while repeating the line of code

```
read -p "Enter user/s: " user user1 user2 user3 
mkdir $user
mkdir $user1
mkdir $user2
mkdir $user3
```

Like, Enter user/s: Michael Raphael Gabriel Satanel Helel... (continuosly to infinite)
then make different directories named from the list of names from prompt by looping the command instead of copy and pasting

Comment: Note that the two duplicates should be read together -- combined, they cover the entire ground of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `read -a arrayname` to read into an array, and `"${arrayname[@]}"` to expand an array to the individual elements it contains.

For `mkdir` specifically, you can pass more than one directory name to a single invocation and let *it* do the looping, to not need to loop in shell at all (we use `xargs` here to split into multiple `mkdir` invocations when the list of usernames is longer than maximum command-line length):

```
read -r -a users
printf '%s\0' "${users[@]}" | xargs -0 mkdir --
```

...but if you *do* want to do the looping in shell, that would look like:

```
read -r -a users
for user in "${users[@]}"; do
  mkdir -- "$user"
done
```